# SSH access via different ports on LAN vs WAN. Is it possible? How to configure?

Tags: ssh, port, openssh

I want to configure OpenSSH to use port 22 for LAN clients, but to use a non-standard port for all outside addresses. How would this be done?

What I have in mind is imagined to be like this:

```
Match Address 192.168.0.0/24
Port 22

Match Address <all others>
Port 2022
```

I'm not sure how to implement it in sshd_config or if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think iptables would be a better solution for this. If the system is behind a NATing router ( most common home setups ) simply forward the non-standard port to the regular port. However if the system is in a DMZ or directly connected to the internet, use iptables to redirect port 2022 to 22.

Comment: @Lamar--it is behind a NATing router. I will use your suggestion to forward the non-standard port to the regular port. Thanks

Comment: This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your OS you can configure port filtering/forwarding to filter any outside rules for port 22 and configure alternative port to do port forwarding to your local port 22